# PHP Laravel array null values after passing to method

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I have a DocumentsController and it stores files.

When I am uploading multiple files, they are uploaded to store method and after that I call a method that manage the path, filename.

So when I pass the data array as parameter to that method(manageFileName), this array somehow is changed, his values are null.

```
class DocumentsController
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');

        $data = [
            "extension" => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
            "name"      => pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName())['filename'],
            "folder"    => $request->folder,
            "visible"   => "private",
            "mime_type" => $file->getClientMimeType()
       ];

        Logger($data);
        /*
           $data = [
            "extension" => 'pdf',
            "name"      => 'pdf sample',
            "folder"    => 'folder',
            "visible"   => "private",
            "mime_type" => 'application/pdf'
           ];
        */

        $this->manageFileName($data);

        // Upload file to S3...
    }

    public function manageFileName($data)
    {
        Logger($data);

        /*
           $data = [
            "extension" => null,  // why?
            "name"      => null,  // why?
            "folder"    => 'folder',
            "visible"   => "private",
            "mime_type" => 'application/pdf'
           ];
        */
    }
}
```

The problem is that this behavior is not happening to all uploaded files, from 20 only 2 or 3 files are not uploaded properly.

I can't understand what is happening.
P.S. I am using Dropzone.js to upload files in Laravel
I am uploading 20 pdf files at a time(just the same file copied).
Laravel 5.8, Php 7.4
I checked php.ini configuration:

- max_file_uploads = 30,
- post_max_size = 50M,
- post_max_size = 50M,
- max_execution_time = 120

Comment: First, create the request object like this `public function store(Request $request)` and then try.

Comment: Sure, I missed it in the question's code